# Two Column bootstrap page with re-ordering and nested columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-layout

I am trying to achieve a two column layout that can be seen here:

https://www.bootply.com/nvbAWqnaC9

I have accomplished this using 'hidden-*' classes to re-order the columns but am wondering if there is a better way to achieve this same layout?

Also, for consideration.. I understand the float left will disrupt the layout if the right column is longer vertically than the left column. I don't expect this to ever be the case but if there is a simple solution I would appreciate hearing it.

Comment: If you describe what it is you are after, I might be able to help you out.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Here is a layout similar to what I am after. https://www.webstaurantstore.com/frymaster-11814e-60-lb-high-production-electric-floor-fryer-with-cm3-5-controls-208v-3-phase-17-kw/36911814ECC.html . On tablet the layout would stay the same. On mobile, the product image would be first, followed by the first 3 sections on the right. After that, the rest of the left column followed by the rest of the right column.

Comment: Use the inspector on the website mentioned and just replicate the order and markup. Seems easy enough.